# When typing code in command line to launch vscode how to avoid this wsh error?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I have a folder which contains a code.js file.

I want to launch vscode from cmd within that folder but when typing "code", I get wsh error. How to force to launch VSCode instead ?

[image]

Comment: An one-shot solution: use `code.cmd` to launch VSCode.  An eternal solution: if output from `set pathext` contains `.js` then remove it from the `pathext` environment variable…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the .js association by typing

```
assoc .js=
```

That will allow cmd to search the %PATH% to find an executable and it will hit vscode as you wanted.

I am sure you realize why this is happening. Windows is looking at the current folder for the command you typed and finds something (code.js) that is executable, and stops looking for another.

Comment: It works, now I have another problem specific to vscode ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949296/why-does-vscode-open-code-js-file-instead-of-current-folder