# Why does vscode open code.js file instead of current folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Subsequent to [When typing code in command line to launch vscode how to avoid this wsh error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928711/when-typing-code-in-command-line-to-launch-vscode-how-to-avoid-this-wsh-error)

I can now launch vscode by typing

code .

But if folder contains code.js file it will open that file instead of current folder.

Why?

I can't see any explanation in doc https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line